# Why does SQL Server add a row null bitmask even if the table has no nullable columns?

Tags: sql-server

Sql server adds a null bitmask to each row to store NULL values for nullable columns, but why does this bitmask exists even if my table has no nullable columns?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does this so that you can make columns nullable or add nullable columns as a metadata-only operation. SQL Server can do this even on the biggest tables instantly, just like it can (often) add, rename or delete columns with a simple metadata change.

I would have implemented this differently. I would have added a field to the page header that stores the current physical schema version that page is using. When the logical schema of the table changes a new physical schema version is created. All new pages use the new format. All modifications to pages with the old format cause a conversion to the new format first.

But SQL Server does not do that. It keeps per-row information that allows for instant schema changes. (It also stores the number of columns per row so that you can easily add columns.)

Comment: The table structure metadata are not stored in the data page so it should already be as you say. The main point of the row null bitmask is to store whether a column is null or not, this way it is easier/faster to retrieve the information.

Comment: @marcob maybe I misunderstood the question? I thought your question is "why does the bitmap exist even with no nullable columns?". Answer: because it is needed for metadata-only operations (might be usedi n the future). Anything unclear in the answer?

Comment: @urs Sorry I hadn't been clear, I understand what you are saying, but it doesn't feel right to me "bloating" row data storage to make 1 metadata operation faster. Having faster switch from non-nullable to nullable in my mind should be a nice side effect of a deeper reason. Meantime I found this article: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/. SQL Server 2000 was storing bits only for nullable columns. They changed it to all columns, as Paul Randal states it is "simpler", I assume referring to the query execution.

Comment: As I said, I would have done it differently, allowing for much more efficient row storage (also the number of columns would not be needed per row, just per page). On the other hand their implementation avoids reformatting the whole page in case of a single-row update. Also avoids page splits.; Meta-data operations are very important once you get to 100GB tables, let me tell you! Very important enterprise feature.